# Manage routes in Vue with vue rotuer problem

Tags: javascript

How can I have a route outside of navigation guards, to access it directly through an external url, without redirecting me to the login route.
The problem is for the password recovery page in which the user does not need to be logged in, if I go to the url https://my-site/recover-password, immediately redirected to the login page.

This is my code in router:

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/check-balance',
    name: 'check-balance',
    component: CheckBalanceComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/check-payment',
    name: 'check-payment',
    component: CheckPaymentsComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/payment-disabled',
    name: 'payment-disabled',
    component: DisabledMakePaymentComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/handle-payment',
    name: 'handle-payment',
    component: HandlePaymentsComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/handle-report',
    name: 'handle-report',
    component: HandleReportsComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/user-profile',
    name: 'user-profile',
    component: UserProfileComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  }, 
  {
    path: '/recover-password', 
    name: 'recover-password',
    component: RecoverPasswordComponent,    
    meta: {
      libre: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/recover-link', 
    name: 'recover-link',
    component: RecoverLinkComponent,
    meta: {
      libre: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    meta: {
      libre: 1
    }
  },
  
  {
    path: '/help',
    name: 'help',
    component: HelpComponent,
    meta: {
      user_type: 1
    }
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.libre)){
    next()
  }   
  else if(store.state.user && store.state.user.user_type == 1){
    next()
  }
  else {
    next({
      name: 'login'
    })
  }
})

export default router
```

Comment: you could probably check in your guard if page path is `recover-password`, ideally create an exception list

Comment: How to create an exception am i new to vue?

Comment: Oh! By exception I don't really mean "Error", I mean a list of routes that shouldn't redirect to /login.

Comment: But in my vue router i have recover-password meta: {libre} and in the navigation guard the source code "if (to.matched.some (record => record.meta.libre)) {next()}", I thought that that was enough for it not to consider the routes with the "libre" meta. which is not the right way to do. Thanks